# How to change the Fill Color selection in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

For some reason, in Office 2013, Microsoft changed the list of colors available for Fill to this:

[image]

It used to have bright green in the palette, but no longer.
[image]

How do I change either the `Standard Colors` or `Theme Colors` selection to bring back the bright green?

Comment: An interesting side effect of this change that I've noticed: I use a system that exports data to .xls with some default cell shading. When I re-save the file as .xlsx, the cell shading changes colors to whatever color is now set in the old color's position in the palette.

Answer (score 1):

On the *Page Layout* tab, click *Colors* (in the *Themes* section), then choose *Customize Colors*. Change any of the Accent colors to the one you desire, then click Save. The change will be reflected in the options under *Theme Colors* in that document.

[image: the new color]

Source: [Change a theme and make it the default in Word or Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-a-theme-and-make-it-the-default-in-Word-or-Excel-c846f997-968e-4daa-b2d4-42bd2afef904?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: Clear and neat answer, compared to tedious q&a on M$ site! Office 2007 only shows 10 standard color iin theme color selection dialog" which is very very bad decision, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Click on **More Colors** at the bottom of your menu and select the color you want.  You will see that this color is added to a row of blank color boxes and when you close the dialog box it should remain in your color selection dropdown menu.

There are a number of ways to keep this color available, the most appropriate is to make it part of Excel's default template, which you can update by Saving As... to where your default template is located, perhaps try:

Applications/Microsoft Office 2013/Office/Startup/Excel

If your computing environment or version of Excel doesn't support setting your own custom template, another workable option is to set the custom colors you want in a new spreadsheet and save it, and then open it by default each time you first start Excel.